# ¿Como escribir en archivos de sistema?

Tags: java, android

Quiero poder escribir en un archivo que es de sistema y que la única forma de lograrlo es con permisos root (Los tengo pero no funciona incluso).

Mi código

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Toast.makeText(this, "Si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
int bytesLeidos = 0;

while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

    os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
}
os.close();
```

Les explico mi código: lo único que hace es solicitar permisos root y abre el contenido del fichero y luego trato de escribir en él mediante los métodos convencionales de java.

### Mi comando

El comando que uso es `su -c cat ruta de archivo`

Comment: Tu haces eso en Android? Y como te imaginas que ejecutar un comando te cambia los privilegios de la vm?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tu aplicación se está ejecutando como root?

Comment: Si porque ademas de realizar esta tarea realiza otras tareas root y las realiza bien y ademas pide la solicitación de permisos root al abrirla. Gracias

Comment: Tu aplicación no funciona con permisos de root, sólo los comandos precedidos por `su` te funcionarán con permisos de root, así que las funciones habituales de `android` seguirán con los permisos de la aplicación.

Comment: Ok, pero no abra una forma de poder escribir en un archivo mediante comandos o cualquier otra forma.Gracias.